# Is there any hook like "pre vagrant up"?

Tags: deployment, vagrant

I'm trying to automate my development boxes with vagrant. I need to share the vagrant setup with other developers, so we need to be sure that some boundary conditions are fullfilled before the normal `vagrant up` process is started.

Is there any hook (like in git, pre-commit or other pre-* scripts) in vagrant? The provision scripts are much too late.

My current setup looks like this:

```
Vagrantfile
vagrant-templates/
vagrant-templates/apache.conf
vagrant-templates/...
sub-project1/
sub-project2/
```

I need to be sure, that sub-project{1..n} exists and if not, there should be a error message.

I would prefer a bash-like solution, but I'm open minded for other solutions.

Comment: I wrote a shell script that bootstraps vagrant projects. You can take a look at it here: https://github.com/marcovanest/strappy

Maybe it's a solution for your problem and otherwise you could scan the code for an anwser

Comment: @cocheese Thank you. Your script is outside from vagrant. This is okay, but I was searching for an inside script. If there is nothing I'll take a closer look at that solution.

Answer (score 25):

You could give a try to this Vagrant plugin I've written:

https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers

Once installed, you could put in your Vagrantfile something like:

```
config.trigger.before :up, :execute => "..."
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the correct one. I was looking for a plugin like that for a long time. Thanks @Emyl!

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: can confirm, sexy af

Answer (score 11):

One option is to put the logic straight into Vagrantfile. Then it gets executed on all `vagrant` commands in the project. For example something like this:

```
def ensure_sub_project(name)
  if !File.exists?(File.expand_path("../#{name}", __FILE__))
    # you could raise or do other ruby magic, or shell out (for a bash script)
    system('clone-the-project.sh', name)
  end
end

ensure_sub_project('some-project')
ensure_sub_project('other-project')

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to write your own plugin for vagrant and use action_hook on the machine_action_up, something like:

```
require 'vagrant-YOURPLUGINNAME/YOURACTIONCLASS'

module VagrantPlugins
  module YOURPLUGINNAME
    class Plugin < Vagrant.plugin('2')
      name 'YOURPLUGINNAME'
      description <<-DESC
          Some description of your plugin
      DESC

      config(:YOURPLUGINNAME) do
        require_relative 'config'
        Config
      end

      action_hook(:YOURPLUGINNAME, :machine_action_up) do |hook|
        hook.prepend(YOURACTIONCLASS.METHOD)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Another plugin to check out is [vagrant-host-shell](https://github.com/phinze/vagrant-host-shell) which is only run when provisioning the box. Just add it before other provisoners in Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision :host_shell do |shell|
  shell.inline = './clone-projects.sh'
  shell.abort_on_nonzero = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

.. adding to tmatilai's answer, you can add something like this:

```
case ARGV[0]
when "provision", "up"
  system "./prepare.sh"
else
  # do nothing
end
```

into your Vagrantfile so that it will only be run on specific commands.